# Text Editor or IDE supporting many languages

Tags: software-development, text-editor, ide, cross-platform

I am looking for a text editor or interactive development environment (IDE) that will support many languages, including but not limited to C, C++, Lisp, Scheme, Fortran, bash, ksh, zsh, m-files (Matlab and Octave).

I use a separate editor for LaTeX and so far I have tried Geany, VIM, Emacs and Notepad++ on Windows.

I write code mainly on Linux, but would like to have a cross-platform editor if possible and I am willing to purchase software if it can meet my demands. So far the best editor, out of the ones I have tried, is VIM but it has a steep learning curve and its GUI is not that helpful. The features I seek apart from these are support for easy commenting in and commenting out with the use of hotkeys and syntax coloring.

Requirements at a glance:

- cross-platform
- syntax highlighting
- easy commenting in/out blocks of texts by the use of hotkeys
- support for multiple programming languages, including but not limited to C, C++, Lisp, Scheme, Fortran, bash, ksh, zsh, m-files
- free is nice, but I am willing to purchase software if it can meet my demands (up to 35$)
- code folding will be nice to have but it is not a must

Comment: SynWrite is ok, all but "cross-plarform", but I know someones use it in Ubuntu too (via Wine).

Comment: What's wrong with the other options you've tried? I use Emacs for all my coding. It's highly customizable, and you could easily have all the features listed. You could also get excellent communtiy help on [Emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So ... basically you have only one requirement - being cross-platform. Because almost any code editor I know of supports the rest of your requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Atom](https://atom.io/)

Atom is a free open-source text and source code editor for Mac OS X, GNU/Linux, and Windows with support for plug-ins written in Node.js, and embedded Git Control, developed by GitHub. Most of the extending packages have free software licenses and are community-built and maintained. Atom is based on Chromium and written in CoffeeScript. It is used also as an IDE

[image: Screenshot of Atom]

and know more about Text Editors @ [**Wikipedia - List of text editors**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors)

Comment: Well thanks for your comment I will check it out.

Comment: Add sublime too , somewhat like atom and native.

Comment: 320 MB package size for a text editor. Not bad

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a recipe for eclipse

http://www.eclipse.org/

- runs on multiple platforms
- Support for lots of syntaxes http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
- free, OSS!
- widely used for C and C++
- fortran support https://eclipse.org/photran/
- scheme support http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemeway/
- matlab support https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/matclipse/
- LISP via multiple plugins, including http://sourceforge.net/projects/dandelion-ecl/
- bash, ksh, other shell: http://toytoygogie.blogspot.com/2010/10/use-shell-editor-for-eclipse-for.html
- Most everything else. Just google  eclipse

Eclipse has a huge user community, and plugins for everything.

It is a full blown IDE, with great editor, comment/uncomment, integration to compilers and interpreters, the works!

Answer (score 2):

Like others who have answered, I like and use both Atom and Eclipse. But both are quite bloated and take a lot of memory to run.

You say you've tried Vim... I think you need to try it again. :) It has a lot of keystrokes to learn, but is incredibly powerful. You can also use gVim which adds menus and toolbars for common commands. You can also run a lot of commands from within the environment, and setup indexing of files, thereby making it a quasi IDE. Best of all, ALL your requirements are checked with (g)Vim.

Comment: you can make vim a real IDE with many plugins https://stackoverflow.com/q/7206469/995714, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE, https://coderoncode.com/tools/2017/04/16/vim-the-perfect-ide.html, https://blog.jez.io/vim-as-an-ide/

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) is app like that. It's simple to middle text editor. Your req's:

- cross-platform: yes
- syntax highlighting: yes
- commenting in/out blocks: yes, commands in Edit menu
- support for programming languages: yes, for 100+ languages, many lexers need to be installed [from ZIP files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synwrite-addons/files/Lexers/)
- freeware
- code folding: yes (for many lexers)

[image: CudaText]

Answer (score 0):

Scite

It meets all of your requirements and is free. It's a nice, light text editor with highlighting for many languages, code folding, shortcuts for commenting out code - either per line or a selection and is available for windows and linux.

Download here: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html